# how call REST service with path variable in webmethod?

Tags: rest, get, webmethod

I'm using WM9.8. I want to know how to call a GET REST service with path variable like:
http://localhost:8080/client/1 in webmethod.

I can call POST rest service using pub.client.http. But it dosen't work to GET.

Answer (score 0):

Use String varible called "method" to set type of Http request method.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the path variable in the URL and made a substitution to the path variable

e.g: http://localhost:8080/client/%yourPathVariableHere%

Answer (score 0):

Holy cow this is an old question but I just tumbled across it and I thought I might helps somebody else who does.

URLs in webmethods are fixed to a single value, like `/client` unless you enable `watt.server.url.alias.partialMatching=true`

After that, you can simply alias a service to `/client` and all subURLs like `/client/1` are sent to that service.  You still have to parse them to get the ID out.

Be careful, though, because ALL sub URLs are sent to the service.  So after enabling this flag I get `/client`, `/client/1`, `/client/1/name` all going to the same service.  You can see how this can quickly become REST-unfriendly.